# Remove GIT Hook in Windows

Tags: windows, git, macos, githooks

I've this script for macOS that removes temporarily a GIT Hook. This script is triggered by an npm script defined in my package.json. This project is shared across the whole team, so it has to work on every machine.

```js
gitdir="$(git rev-parse --git-dir)"
hook="$gitdir/hooks/post-commit"

# disable post-commit hook temporarily
[ -x $hook ] && chmod -x $hook

git add -A
git commit --amend --allow-empty --no-edit  --no-verify

# enable it again
chmod +x $hook
```

Can someone help me transcribe this to a .bat in order to be able to excute this in windows?

Comment: Install git for windows, use git bash to execute it. https://gitforwindows.org/

Comment: @Tschallacka thanks for the advice. I edited my question. This is part of my package.json as an npm script command. How do I run the git bash from there?

Comment: Install NPM/node for windows https://nodejs.org/en/, install git for windows. In the folder where your project is, right click, open git bash here, then just run your usual commands. Git for windows makes working on windows a lot easier. What you can also do if you have windows 10 is install the linux subsystem(google it) and run in a proper linux enviroment

Comment: @Tschallacka I can't right click anything...this is a npm script command that should be run when invoked from console "npm run task"

Comment: Have you ever worked with windows?  In the file explorer, you can right click and you get a context menu. In your project folder you can do this too. Then from the dropdown select "Open git bash here" Then run all npm commands whatever you need after installing the above mentioned packages to get this auto runner running

Comment: You'll need to adopt a different approach than changing the executable bit on Windows, since Windows doesn't know about the executable bit. You'll probably have to temporarily move the file to the side instead.